# Does Repo tool have any versioning commands

Tags: android, git, repo

My use case is multiple Git repos with inter-dependencies and each repo had different versions e.g.

- Repo A has pom.xml with version 1.0
- Repo B has pom.xml with version 2.0 and depends on jars from Repo A
- Repo C has pom.xml with version 3.0 and depends on jars from Repo A & B

Does Android Repo tool use any versioning commands to set project version and update dependency versions?

Answer (score 0):

Quotation from [manifest-format.txt](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo/+/master/docs/manifest-format.txt)

> Attribute `revision`: Name of the Git branch the manifest wants
>   to track for this project.  Names can be relative to refs/heads
>   (e.g. just "master") or absolute (e.g. "refs/heads/master").
>   Tags and/or explicit SHA-1s should work in theory, but have not
>   been extensively tested.  If not supplied the revision given by
>   the remote element is used if applicable, else the default
>   element is used.

If you have marked version with tags, you can specify version in manifest file with revision attribute.